# AssetManager public constructor not accessible

Tags: android

When I view the android source code for class AssetManager, I've found it has a public constructor. But it's so weird that I cannot use the "new" keyword to create an instance. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think they mean this public constructor:
https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/content/res/AssetManager.java#L87

```
/**
 * Create a new AssetManager containing only the basic system assets.
 * Applications will not generally use this method, instead retrieving the
 * appropriate asset manager with {@link Resources#getAssets}.    Not for
 * use by applications.
 * {@hide}
 */
public AssetManager() {
   ...snip...
}
```

The reason you can't access it is because of the sneaky `@hide` attribute in the Javadocs... the Android framework has a bunch of methods which are for internal use only and are blocked from application use via that attribute.

Answer (score 0):

According to the official Android documentation, AssetManager does not offer a public constructor

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html

Can you paste the link to the source code that has you intrigued?

Comment: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/content/res/AssetManager.java#AssetManager.%3Cinit%3E%28%29

Comment: @karaokyo Why go through third party sites for code when it's there on github! https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/content/res/AssetManager.java and what do you know! AssetManager does indeed have a public constructor!!